# grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,ncol = 2) shows error

Tags: r, gridextra

I have two plots that work fine individually and now I'm trying to put them side by side by using gridExtra::grid.arrange but it shows error. this is fairly easy code but not sure where I get the error? and it actually kills R and I have to reboot.

```
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,ncol = 2)
```

error message:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too
>   deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? Error during
>   wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)?

Comment: More info is needed. Can you show how your plots are generated please?

Comment: I don't see that you loaded `grid`